# Qt - check availability of linked .lib on windows with preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, windows, qt, linker, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use preprocessor directives in C++ for avoiding to compile code that requires a .lib, in case the library cannot be linked.

My .pro file contains:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Windows Kits/8.0/Include/um"
LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Windows Kits/8.0/Lib/win8/um/x86" -l"winscard"
```

and my directives are of the form:

```
#ifdef _WINSCARD_H_
// do something
#endif
```

or

```
#ifndef _WINSCARD_H_
// do something
#endif
```

This **winscard** comes with [this windows sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) and I can definitely use its functionalities. The problems arise when I try to restrict the compilation based on these conditional directives.

---

Code compiles fine when using

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Windows Kits/8.0/Include/um"
LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Windows Kits/8.0/Lib/win8/um/x86" -l"winscard"
```

in the .pro file.

Code is skipped during the compilation phase, as if the library is missing when using the above .pro configurations and the conditional directive, even though the library is available and linked:

```
#ifdef _WINSCARD_H_
// code that needs to be compiled only when library is present and linked.
#endif
```

The only change is the introduction of `#ifdef _WINSCARD_H_`.

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. What did you try and what error you receive?

Comment: Edited with explanations. There is no error. The only problem is that the code that needs to be compiled is skipped when introducing #ifdef _ WINSCARD_H _, even when the library is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to generate conditional build in qmake basing on file existence.
You can add in your `.pro` file something like that

```
exists( C:/Program Files/Windows Kits/8.0/Lib/win8/um/x86/winscard* ) {
    message( "Configuring for winscard..." )
    INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files/Windows Kits/8.0/Include/um"
    LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files/Windows Kits/8.0/Lib/win8/um/x86" -l"winscard"
    DEFINES += _WINSCARD_H_
}
```

The block after the built-in function `exists()` is parsed only when the path is found (it is possible to use asterisk to match part of filename). Here `_WINSCARD_H_` is defined only if required file is found.
So, that macro can be used in source code for conditional compilation.
See [qmake Test Functions Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html) for details.

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you! This should work. However, `_WINSCARD_H_` is already supposed to be defined in the `windscard.h` header. That is precisely what is confusing to me, the fact that the symbol isn't recognized.

Comment: @user3741113 It is just an example. You can choose some unque name of that macro definition suitable for naming conventions of your project.

Comment: It is a useful method indeed. Would've preferred to use their unique name directly. Nevertheless, thank you for the help!